# How to make setStudentName method?

Tags: java, string

I'm supposed to kinda create a student account in java (I'm very new to Java so please don't flame me). Everything is working fine except for when I need to set a Name/degree program (so string I believe). By the way, I'm using BlueJ.

I have tried using the void instead of string but I get the same problem. I also did this before the method starts:

```
private String studentName;
public String setStudentName (String setStudentName) {
    return studentName = setStudentName;
}
```

I just want to set the Student Name so I can work with it, but if I try running it, I get the following error: "Error: cannot find symbol - variable Robin" Robin is the Name I tried to enter.

Comment: Setters don't return anything. Change the return type to `void` and remove the `return`. You're also probably missing the quotes from around the String, so instead of `"Robin"`, you've written `Robin` (which would look for a variable named Robin, which doesn't exist).

Comment: Sounds like you accidentally typed "Robin" into your source code window instead of your console window.  Yeah, it happens, even to us old-timers (_sigh_)

Comment: @Kayaman, a setter can return something if you define it. By doing it you gain the methods chain feature.

Comment: @user2342558 fluent builders are one thing, but a JavaBean setter does not return anything.

Comment: It looks to me like you need to add more code to fully explain your problem since it seems to be related to more than just the set method

Comment: well i tried all of what you guys suggested, still get the error... even tried a new class but nope. Remember, im using BlueJ so i dont know if that makes a difference..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class and methods should look something like this:

```
public final class Student {
    private String studentName;

    public String getStudentName() {
        return studentName;
    }

    public void setStudentName(String studentName) {
        this.studentName = studentName;
   }
}
```

Then, you can use your class like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Student student = new Student();
    student.setStudentName("Robin");
    System.out.println(student.getStudentName());
}
```

Take a look into the official [Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html) on how to write classes.

Comment: So i tried it out... same problem. The getStudentName method i had before, if i use it i get 'null' as the name. Why did you put 'this.' before studentName?

Comment: I've put `this` in there so that Java knows that it refers to field `studentName` (the one in the second line) and not to the parameter of the `setStudentName` method which has the same name. You probably get `null` because you first have to use `setStudentName` before calling `getStudentName`. Otherwise, the variable won't have been initialized when `getStudentName` is called and hence be `null`

Comment: @rxbxi I've added an example on how to use these methods.

Comment: ill try it out... will tell ya if it worked for me (Y)

Comment: so i guess i figured it out myself... my code works too i think, all i have to do is write the name (when using the method) into these "" things... xd so like this: "Robin"

Answer (score -1):

Just want to sum up all responses above, you have to write `this.studentName = studentName` instead of `studentName = studentName`, because in your context you have both method class field and method parameter `studentName`, so if you write inside your method `studentName` you work with method parameter. `this` is link to 'class instance itself' and `this.studentName`calls exactly class field.

One more solution is to rename `studentName` method param to e.g. `newStudentName` so it wouldn't be in conflict with class field and afterwords `studentName = newStudentName` will work as you expects.